# Use a UIGestureRecognizer to get the coordinates whenever the finger moves?

Tags: objective-c, slider, uigesturerecognizer, jailbreak, user-interaction

I am trying to make a slider, where an image slides with the finger, left to right. I want to use a UIGestureRecognizer. How do I make it so it for this purpose, logs out the coordinates of the finger, every time the finger moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UIPanGestureRecognizer* pgr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(handlePan:)];
   [self.panningView addGestureRecognizer:pgr];

}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pgr;
{
   if (pgr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
      CGPoint center = pgr.view.center;
      imageView.center = center;

   }
}
```

Comment: Another way to accomplish this is by using `[pgr locationInView:self.view]` and it will give you a `CGPoint` of where each touch is located. For a slider, you would just use the x value most likely.